# Passing data from Directive to Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

Here is the directive, which listens to key strokes on any component:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[keyCatcher]' })
export class keyCatcher {
    @HostListener('document:keydown', [ '$event' ])
    onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        alert(event.key);
    }
}
```

the KeyCatcher is used in the HTML portion of a custom component.

How can I pass the event.key to the component.ts using the KeyCatcher?

Is this usually done through a service?

Comment: How does the dependency structure look? Is the directive used in the component that needs to be notified? If so just use an event (@Output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8rqqrc

Using an @Output of [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in the directive allows you to bind a function to it from the parent to read the event stream.